# nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet - Hibernate

Tags: java, linux, spring, postgresql, hibernate

In my spring-boot app, I have a login jsp page that I am able to login successfully from windows using postgres db locally. On building the war file and deployed to linux, I am having this error from my browser on attempting to login

```
There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
could not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
```

this is the configuration in my application.properties file

```
db.driver: org.postgresql.Driver
db.url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/dbName
db.username: dbUsername
db.password: password4321
hibernate.dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL9Dialect
hibernate.show_sql: true
hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto: update
```

on hitting the submit button of the form, it hits this controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView authenticateLogin(HttpServletRequest request,
                                   HttpServletResponse response,
                                   @RequestParam String email,
                                   @RequestParam String password) {

        if(null == request.getSession().getAttribute(data))
        {

            //fetch the list of logins
            List add =  _loginDao.getAllUsernameByEmail(email);
            //fetch the list of support password
            List passList = _loginDao.getAllUserPassword(password);
```

**EDITTED:** This is the hql query I am using on wwindows

```
public List <Login> getAllUsernameByEmail(String email)
    {

        String hql = "select a.email from Login a WHERE a.email = :email AND a.active = true";
        return _sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery(hql).setParameter("email", email).list();

    }
    public List <Login> getAllUserPassword(String password)
    {

        String hql = "select a.password from Login a WHERE a.password = :password AND a.active = true";
        return _sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery(hql).setParameter("password", password).list();

    }
```

Please what could be wrong?

Comment: Post the generated queries on windows and on linux. You might be facing some case sensitive problem

Comment: you are using hibernate and with `hibernate.show_sql` you are showing the generated queries hibernate creates. Also, add the table names as well, to check if the `from` sql clause matches the hibernate query

Comment: How do I add the table names. Thanks

Comment: You have to `select a from` instead of `select a.email from` and `a.password from`. You're only extracting one field, but it looks like you're trying to extract the whole `Login` objects.

Comment: Could you post the full stacktrace?